# Qiskit: PauliOp from string

Tags: qiskit

I save my (lenghty) Hamiltonian in a file as a string.

My naive attempt:

```
hamiltonian_string = read_hamiltonian_from_file()  # some function
hamiltonian = PauliOp(hamiltonian_string) 
TypeError: PauliOp can only be instantiated with Paulis, not <class 'str'>
```

But copy-pasting from the file into Jupyter notebook works (of course):

```
hamiltonian =  1*(X^X^X) - 2*(X^Z^X) + 3*(X^I^X)
print(type(hamiltonian))
<class 'qiskit.opflow.primitive_ops.pauli_sum_op.PauliSumOp'>
```

Is there a way to initiate a PauliOp from a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use Python's [`eval()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval):

```
from qiskit.opflow import I, X, Y, Z

hamiltonian_string = '1*(X^X^X) - 2*(X^Z^X) + 3*(X^I^X)'
hamiltonian = eval(hamiltonian_string)
print(type(hamiltonian))
```

There are some security concerns regarding `eval()` you need to be aware of. See [here](https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#minimizing-the-security-issues-of-eval) for details.

Comment: Amazing, thank you!
Works like a charm :)